# When is it desirable to miss color block or hit spikes?

Tags: audiosurf-2

In Audiosurf 2, on the mono mode (the mode where there is only one color of block), my strategy has been to simply hit all the blocks I could, while missing spikes.

I've played through some songs missing only a couple of blocks, yet missing the the high score by a large factor, so I'm assuming my strategy is flawed, and I need to miss some to get an optimal score. When should I choose to miss blocks?

Comment: I may be being pessimistic, but in the original Audiosurf it was incredibly easy to cheat. It's possible the high score is simply not a legitimate score.

Comment: @DBS AudioSurf 2's scores are legitimate. Using the right combos on power-loop blocks can get upwards of 22K+ on your score. It's more advantageous to have a full grid than to get every brick possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mono mode, you gain points on two occasions : when you hit a block in an already full column, or after a certain time if you have three or more connected blocks. In each case, **more connected blocks mean more points**. Moreover, the more blocks you have, the more each block is worth (the 20th block is worth more than the 15th, and a 18 combo is better than two 9 combos)

Therefore, your objective is to score only when you have many blocks ; it can be better to miss a few blocks which would end your combo, to pick others. It is all about **balance**.

There are also special blocks, which give you your current combo points when you hit them **without emptying the grid** ; you also want to hit them when your grid is full. Hence it can be worth it to hit a spike to be able to maintain your combo a little longer.

And of course, as you gain points for a **clean finish**, you should avoid hitting the last blocks if you cannot get a combo with them.

*Note : This **has** changed from Audiosurf 1. Now, hitting blocks doesn't give any point, neither does achieving a "stealth" run (no spikes hit - in the first game, it gave a good 30% boost to final score).*

Answer (score 2):

I've only played Audiosurf 1, so I'm not sure how much this applies to 2, though I imagine the mechanics are largely unchanged.

Assuming all of the scores are legitimate, there are two things that could be getting people much higher scores than you: bigger matches and chaining.

Before I get into that there's one important concept you need to consider: the delay between a block landing in your grid and when the blocks finish matching and disappear. In Audiosurf 1, this delay was represented by a shape inside the colored blocks, which got smaller over time. Doing *anything* to your grid will reset this delay -- hitting another block (both colored and greys) and even removing greys.

The first thing, bigger matches, is pretty straightforward: the more colored blocks you have in your grid when they finish matching, the more points you get for it. Bigger matches are worth more than smaller matches combined, so a big match of 21 is worth much more than matches of 18 and 3.

It's worth mentioning that the delay period I mentioned will immediately finish if you try putting another block into a column that's already full.

The second thing is a bit more complicated. After you complete a match, there's a short window afterwards, where, if you continue hitting blocks and keeping your "delay" going, you'll get bonus points. In Audiosurf 1, this was represented by a small horizontal bar on the bottom of your screen getting progressively bigger, but I don't know what it looks like in Audiosurf 2.

If you keep this chain alive as long as possible, you will get more and more points! Again, like with the delay, doing anything to your grid will keep the chain alive, even if you don't currently have any matches going.

It might be more difficult to do in mono mode, but I know in the other modes a common tactic was to try and get many small matches at the beginning of a song to quickly build up the chain.

On the other hand, if Audiosurf 2 still has the massive bonus at the end for not hitting a single grey, that could outweigh the benefit you get from more chaining.

Make sure you're only weighing your score against other mono players. Mono just isn't good on certain types of songs!

Comment: AudioSurf 2 has a bonus for a clean finish, ex. the board is cleared at the end. There is no bonus for missing all spikes in Mono. In Mono Turbo, there is a Ninja bonus for not hitting any spikes.